# Can a lissajous curve be used for data compression or encryption?

Tags: encryption, compression

A lissajous curve with
X=cos(t)
Y=sin(sqrt(2)*t)
I believe can be used to map two numbers on a point x and y onto a single number t.
Because the graph goes through every point
On the rectangle from -1 to 1 and -1 to 1.

Comment: ... the question looks too broad, not very specific and not very practical. Try another site (although computers can't handle arbitrary exact real numbers anyway

Comment: Mapping two numbers to one won't give you any compression if you need twice as many bits in the one number to extract the original data. Which you would.